# sort behaves weirdly with scientific notation

Tags: sort

I have a file with semicolon separated fields, which I want to sort according to general numeric value of the 26th column. I tried this:

```
cat file.txt | grep -v setch | sort -t";" -k26 -g
```

The grep command is there to filter out some lines I don't want.

The file after the grep command looks like this:

```
5;0;0;0;0;17;0.040000;3.00;17;0.030000;2.00;17;0.040000;7.00;11.5833330154419;11.5833330154419;11.5833330154419;0.522556364536285;312.500000000000;-1384.20000000000;39.0625000000000;6000.00000000000;;;;;;;;;;33.15;;X;;E;
5;0;0;0;0;17;0.040000;3.00;17;0.020000;3.00;17;0.040000;7.00;11.5833330154419;11.5833330154419;11.5833330154419;0.522556364536285;312.500000000000;-1384.20000000000;39.0625000000000;6000.00000000000;;;;-7.18901342e+02;-7.78309691e+01;-7.78225676e+01;-7.78079745e+01;-7.77838466e+01;;39.3333333333333;;X;;E;
5;0;0;0;0;17;0.040000;3.00;17;0.020000;20.00;17;0.040000;7.00;11.5833330154419;11.5833330154419;11.5833330154419;0.522556364536285;312.500000000000;-1384.20000000000;39.0625000000000;6000.00000000000;;;;-7.78309996e+01;-7.78285783e+01;-7.78259409e+01;-7.78212922e+01;-7.78200550e+01;;39.8166666666667;;X;;E;
5;0;0;0;0;17;0.040000;3.00;17;0.030000;3.00;17;0.040000;7.00;11.5833330154419;11.5833330154419;11.5833330154419;0.522556364536285;312.500000000000;-1384.20000000000;39.0625000000000;6000.00000000000;;;;-9.38492178e+02;-5.44898488e+02;-7.78311132e+01;-7.78228037e+01;-7.78082194e+01;;40.6166666666667;;X;;E;
5;0;0;0;0;17;0.040000;3.00;17;0.030000;8.00;17;0.040000;7.00;11.5833330154419;11.5833330154419;11.5833330154419;0.522556364536285;312.500000000000;-1384.20000000000;39.0625000000000;6000.00000000000;;;;-7.78321216e+01;-7.78265847e+01;-7.78213151e+01;-7.78175760e+01;-7.78102439e+01;;40.4833333333333;;X;;E;
5;0;0;0;0;17;0.040000;3.00;17;0.030000;15.00;17;0.040000;7.00;11.5833330154419;11.5833330154419;11.5833330154419;0.522556364536285;312.500000000000;-1384.20000000000;39.0625000000000;6000.00000000000;;;;-7.78326108e+01;-7.78282041e+01;-7.78246496e+01;-7.78216823e+01;-7.78198536e+01;;40.0333333333333;;X;;E;
5;0;0;0;0;17;0.040000;3.00;17;0.020000;15.00;17;0.040000;7.00;11.5833330154419;11.5833330154419;11.5833330154419;0.522556364536285;312.500000000000;-1384.20000000000;39.0625000000000;6000.00000000000;;;;-7.78317280e+01;-7.78275891e+01;-7.78237230e+01;-7.78209144e+01;-7.78197521e+01;;44.3;;X;;E;
5;0;0;0;0;17;0.040000;3.00;17;0.030000;10.00;17;0.040000;7.00;11.5833330154419;11.5833330154419;11.5833330154419;0.522556364536285;312.500000000000;-1384.20000000000;39.0625000000000;6000.00000000000;;;;-7.78322942e+01;-7.78274590e+01;-7.78225495e+01;-7.78192915e+01;-7.78148301e+01;;43.65;;X;;E;
5;0;0;0;0;17;0.040000;3.00;17;0.020000;8.00;17;0.040000;7.00;11.5833330154419;11.5833330154419;11.5833330154419;0.522556364536285;312.500000000000;-1384.20000000000;39.0625000000000;6000.00000000000;;;;-7.78322863e+01;-7.78266434e+01;-7.78211618e+01;-7.78173451e+01;-7.78097348e+01;;45.4833333333333;;X;;E;
5;0;0;0;0;17;0.040000;3.00;17;0.030000;4.00;17;0.040000;7.00;11.5833330154419;11.5833330154419;11.5833330154419;0.522556364536285;312.500000000000;-1384.20000000000;39.0625000000000;6000.00000000000;;;;-7.61265100e+02;-7.78321802e+01;-7.78247066e+01;-7.78104129e+01;-7.78053976e+01;;44.8833333333333;;X;;E;
```

The output is however not sorted according to general numerical value, but according to numerical value (without reference to the powers).

Is there anything I can do to get sort to do what I want?

Update: This is the output of the above pipe (only the relevant column shown), and it is also the output of `sort -t\; -g -k26,26`, which was suggested in the answer.

```
-9.38492178e+02
-7.78317280e+01
-7.78309996e+01
-7.18901342e+02
-7.78322863e+01
-7.78322942e+01
-7.78326108e+01 
-7.61265100e+02
-7.78321216e+01
```

Comment: works for me. What version of `sort` are you using

Comment: @1_CR I can't check right know, it's on a different machine

Comment: what OS & Version is it?  Linux? Mac? Solaris? FreeBSD? Other?

Comment: Please post an example of the incorrectly sorted output.

Comment: sort (GNU coreutils) 8.4 is the version, and I'm guessing it's Linux, it's a machine I log in to to do calculations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

note the difference in output between these two pipelines:

```
<yourexample \
sort -t\; -gk26 |
cut -d\; -f26
```

---

```
-7.18901342e+02
-7.78309996e+01
-9.38492178e+02
-7.78321216e+01
-7.78326108e+01
-7.78317280e+01
-7.78322942e+01
-7.78322863e+01
-7.61265100e+02
```

...and...

```
<yourexample \
sort -t\; -gk26,26 |
cut -d\; -f26
```

---

```
-9.38492178e+02
-7.61265100e+02
-7.18901342e+02
-7.78326108e+01
-7.78322942e+01
-7.78322863e+01
-7.78321216e+01
-7.78317280e+01
-7.78309996e+01
```

sorting *just* on `-k`ey 26 is the same as sorting *from* key 26 through to the end of the line, but sorting on `-k`ey 26,26 sorts *only* on that key. if you want to consider other fields in the sort order as tie breakers, add more `-k`eys - but be specific.

---

All that aside, [you've commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247481/sort-behaves-weirdly-with-scientific-notation#comment425989_247481) that you're working with a [5-year-old GNU Coreutils](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=6145) package. Curious, I skipped through a few changelogs after your release, and this stood out within two releases [*(Oct 2010 for v8.6)*](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=6553):

> `sort -g` now uses long doubles for greater range and precision.
>
> `sort -h` no longer rejects numbers with leading or trailing `.`, and no longer accepts numbers with multiple `.`.  It now considers all zeros to be equal.

You might update.

Comment: Oh, well, I guess I have to ask the administrator of the machine if he can update sort for me, it doesn't look like I can do it myself. Anyway, thanks for the explanation and the hint about the version, at least I now know why it doesn't work.

Comment: @fifaltra - you could locate a personal build in `~/bin` or something and `PATH=~/bin:$PATH`.